# каким образом можно передать данные из .txt файла в тело http сообщения

Tags: python-3.x

Возникла необходимость передачи некоторой информации из файла `test.txt` *http* запросом на прокси сервер. При этом, передать необходимо не сам файл, а содержимое, добавив к нему текущую дату и время.
Тип *http* запроса `post`.
Для работы с запросами используется **python** `requests(version 3.4)`.

Comment: Наводка - https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/ + https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_func_open.asp

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from time import time
import json


data = json.dumps({"data": open('test.txt', 'r', encoding='UTF-8').read(), "timestamp": time()})

r = requests.post("http://example.com", data=data)
print(r.text)
```

Можно делать так. Разве что дата и время выражены в виде `timestamp`